# Get field in readable word

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, user-meta

I added a custom user meta field named "Country".
Code for adding the custom field:

```
// ADD EXTRA PROFILE FIELD
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3 class="extra-info">Extra Info</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="country">Country</label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="country" id="country" >
                <?php
                    $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'country', true ) );
                    foreach ( array(
                        'not-selected' => '',
                        'south-africa' => 'South Africa',
                        'south-korea' => 'South Korea',
                        'spain' => 'Spain',
                        'ukraine' => 'United Arab Emirates',
                        'united-kingdom' => 'United Kingdom (UK)',
                        'united-states' => 'United States (US)',
                        'venezuela' => 'Venezuela',
                        'vietnam' => 'Vietnam',
                    ) as $value => $label ) :
                        $selected = selected( $value, $_value, false );
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'extrainfo_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'extrainfo_save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extrainfo_save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'country', $_POST['country'] );
}
```

So, in the backend, it shows "United States (US)". But when I echo it in a shortcode to display them on the frontend for the current user, it shows "united-states".

This is my shortcode to show the current user's country:

```
    // USERS' COUNTRY
function user_country_info_shortcode() {
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $country = get_user_meta($user_id, 'country', true);

if (!empty($country)) {
    echo $country;
    } else { 
    echo 'Add your country';
    }
}
}
add_shortcode('currentuser_country_info', 'user_country_info_shortcode');
```

How to make it show "United States (US)" instead, on the frontend, in a shortcode?

Comment: You should include in your question, the full code you use for adding the custom field.

Comment: @SallyCJ sorry, I've edit and included it now.

Comment: if my answer helped you, you can [accept](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it and/or [upvote](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it when you have the vote *privilege*. And if you need further assistance, just let me know. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Updated/new answer)*

> How to make it show "United States (US)" instead, on the frontend, in
>   a shortcode?

First off, you got `united-states` (the country slug/key) instead of `United States (US)` (the country name) because your `extrainfo_save_extra_user_profile_fields()` function is saving the country slug/key instead of the country name. That's not a problem, and I'd do the same thing.

**However, to display the proper country *name* based on its slug/key,** then:

An easy way, is by copying the country slugs/keys and names `array` from your `extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields()` function to your shortcode function; e.g.:

```
function user_country_info_shortcode() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $country = get_user_meta($user_id, 'country', true);

        if (!empty($country)) {
            $countrys = array(
                'not-selected' => '',
                'south-africa' => 'South Africa',
                'south-korea' => 'South Korea',
                'spain' => 'Spain',
                'ukraine' => 'United Arab Emirates',
                'united-kingdom' => 'United Kingdom (UK)',
                'united-states' => 'United States (US)',
                'venezuela' => 'Venezuela',
                'vietnam' => 'Vietnam',
            );

            $country = isset( $countrys[ $country ] ) ? $countrys[ $country ] : $country;

            echo $country;
        } else { 
            echo 'Add your country';
        }
    }
}
```

But for more flexibility — no need to edit *both* the functions code just to change a specific country slug/key and/or name, then I strongly suggest you to go with the other option below, particularly if and when you have a (very) long list of countries:

In the theme functions file (e.g. `wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/functions.php`), *or* in your plugin file which stores *global* functions, add this:

```
// List of country slugs and names.
function my_user_country_list() {
    return array(
        'not-selected' => '',
        'south-africa' => 'South Africa',
        'south-korea' => 'South Korea',
        'spain' => 'Spain',
        'ukraine' => 'United Arab Emirates',
        'united-kingdom' => 'United Kingdom (UK)',
        'united-states' => 'United States (US)',
        'venezuela' => 'Venezuela',
        'vietnam' => 'Vietnam',
    );
}
```

Then in the `extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields()` function, replace the `foreach` (opening line) so that it utilizes the `my_user_country_list()` function, like this:

```
function extrainfo_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3 class="extra-info">Extra Info</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="country">Country</label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="country" id="country" >
                <?php
                    $_value = trim( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'country', true ) );
                    foreach ( my_user_country_list() as $value => $label ) :
                        $selected = selected( $value, $_value, false );
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php }
```

And then, in your `user_country_info_shortcode()` function, you can retrieve the user's country (i.e. the country *name*) like so: *(re-indented for clarity)*

```
function user_country_info_shortcode() {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $country = get_user_meta($user_id, 'country', true);

        if (!empty($country)) {
            $countrys = my_user_country_list();
            $country = isset( $countrys[ $country ] ) ? $countrys[ $country ] : $country;

            echo $country;
        } else { 
            echo 'Add your country';
        }
    }
}
```

*Sorry for the many edits, but hopefully this "new" answer would be of more help than the original answer (or the previous revisions of this answer).*